# Referencing values in an output table

Tags: powershell

I dont know powershell that well but do use some scripts I get from the web to assist with particular tasks.  One such script I use (provided by Jonathan Almquist), is for checking is Ops Manager Alert Grooming is working.  His script is as follows

$Threshold=(Get-Date).AddDays(-(get-defaultsetting)[42].Value-1).ToUniversalTime().Date.AddMinutes(30);Get-Alert | Where {$*.TimeResolved -and $*.TimeResolved -lt $Threshold} | Measure-Object

The output of this is a table in the form:

```
Count    : 0
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

Basically if the valus for count is 0 then all good but higher numbers indicate an issue.

What I want to to is be able to store the value of count, so I can reference the outputted result.

Can anyone advise how I can amend the script so the table values (eg count = 0) can be later references in a vaiable or the like?

any help much apreciated!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the properties you get back belong to the result object of the `Measure-Object` cmdlet. Assign the results of the `Get-Alert` command to a variable and then access its Count property.

```
$Threshold=(Get-Date).AddDays(-(get-defaultsetting)[42].Value-1).ToUniversalTime().Date.AddMinutes(30)
$Alerts = Get-Alert | Where {$_.TimeResolved -and $_.TimeResolved -lt $Threshold} | Measure-Object

$Alerts.Count
```